# How do I solve invalid credentials or usernames when connecting to Remote Desktop on Windows 10?

Tags: remote-desktop, remote, windows-10

It works on my local account but not when I connect my **Microsoft Windows Account**.

Remote Desktop Settings:

[image: Remote Desktop Settings]

Port 3389 is open:
[image: Port 3389]

- Tried both my Local IP  as well as my public IP for the PC Name.
- MicrosoftAccount\google@gmail.com  for the (DOMAIN/user)
- I've even reset my Microsoft account password and have verified it's the correct one.
- I verified my Windows Firewall Inbound Rules.
- When I use the Microsoft Remote Desktop Assistant it just gives my local IP/username info which is what I tried above.. same as the whoami output.
- My network is indeed set to private.

I tried to connect via my Phone/laptop both ON the Wi-Fi using my local IP and disconnected from WiFi (LTE) using the public IP. Just says, "The user name or password did not work" or "Invalid Credentials."

Any ideas?

Comment: There are two important factors to consider. First of all, the machine that you are trying to access via RDP is utilizing Windows 10 **Pro** and not the **Home** version, correct?  Last but not least, in your first screen shot that `Select users...` button is crucial.  Essentially, the account you are using to RDP into the distant-end machine needs to either be a member of one of two groups on the remote machine:  either the **Administrators** group or the **Remote Desktop Users** group.

Comment: I've suffered the same. I know there is a problem logging into Win10 from Win7 and visa versa. If no one else chimes in, late tonight I'll look to see if I figured it out. Can't remember if I broke through or gave up a year ago.

Comment: Oh, and all machines have to be on the same Work Group, in Win 10 it's something similar different name.

Comment: So I logged into RDP as a local user.. then switched back to my microsoft account and it worked. Not sure why.. :/

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Ensure you have a local account on the computer you are trying to access.

Step 2: Make sure that account is in the list of users (screenshot above)

Step 3: Enabling remote desktop means you must have a password that conforms to 8 characters minimum, one number, one capital and one non-alpha-numeric.

After confirming you have done all that correctly you will be able to login. As you can already see the login screen the problem has nothing to do with your firewall.

Comment: There is no password length or complexity requirement for RDP. There just *has* to be a password.

Answer (score 0):

Please be shure your keyboard layout in RDP is the correct one (corresponding with the keyboard of your host PC). Otherwise a password having a non-alpha-numeric character will not be mapped correct to windows 10

Answer (score 0):

I used to connect to Windows 7 with the local username & password, but that did not work on Windows 10 anymore.

I can connect to Windows 10 with the email & password associated with my Microsoft Account in Windows 10. I tested on a Big Sur Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I had just fixed my problem. It seems like one of the updates installed within the last 6 months broke authentication for me. Had a clean install of Windows in the beginning of the year, configured all my devices that needed connectivity when needed. Then when I actually needed it, authentication failed no matter what.

In my case, I was logged in to Windows since setting up initially with my Microsoft account linked. **I disconnected my Microsoft account** to use a local account, **then reconnected the Microsoft account**. Apparently, something broke in the cached password or something because I was able to log in via RDP with my Microsoft account credentials and access my shares.